# How to Detect a visitor (client) DNS server IP using Logical methods

Tags: domain-name-system, php

I understand there is no way for a webserver to detect the DNS IP of an incoming request becuase that data is not stored in any packet option.  Raw TCP http data is all the webserver is use to seeing.   So my question is this - How can I integrate a healthcheck tool that will let the user know if he is configured with my DNS server as opposed to his ISP DNS.

I run my own DNS with a unique healcheck URL (ie. check.example.com)

This URL will respond with a 1.1.1.1 if Queried using my DNS and 127.0.0.1 if Queries using any outside DNS.

Given this advantage is there any sort of PHP script I can use to force the customers browser to perform a DNS Query using the client side environment then invoke a status message (success or fail) based on the response ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is server-side so you're not going to be able to make the browser do anything with PHP. You may be able to with Javascript but I've never come across any way of sending a DNS query from a web page.

The most obvious solution to me would be to send an AJAX web request from the webpage to a URL that only resolves when using your DNS. If the request succeeds then you know the user is using your DNS servers. If not it will time out.